# How can you find what client browser is being used in a session for a GWT project?

Tags: gwt, browser

I used:

```
Navigator.getUserAgent().toLowerCase()
```

but the output I got for that was something like this:

```
mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/27.0.1453.94 safari/537.36
```

I am using Chrome and developing in Eclipse. I could probably just look for strings like "chrome" or "firefox" in the output, but note that the output contains both "chrome" and "safari". Is there some alternative API for this?

At the very least, is it possible to determine if the browser is a mobile (iphone/android phone), tablet (ipad) or desktop (chrome / IE/ firefox)?

Comment: Sniffing is the only way and is not recommended -- why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to produce responsive web design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a browser-compatible views for a GWT Application, you should add browser-specific views if you like.

```
<replace-with class="com.example.PopupInSafari">
   <when-type-is class="com.example.Popup"/>
   <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
</replace-with>
```

To check if your application is viewed on mobile, you can:

```
String mUserAgent = Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().toLowerCase();
boolean isInIosDevice = mUserAgent.contains( "ipad" ) 
                        || mUserAgent.contains( "iphone" );
boolean isInMobile = mUserAgent.contains( "mobile" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to determine which type of client used. The solution will be more convenient if you implement native GWT feature.

See:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#replacement

Also you can use custom JavaScript provider with custom properties.

https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/blob/master/gwtp-core/gwtp-mvp-client/src/main/resources/com/gwtplatform/mvp/FormFactor.gwt.xml

P.S. https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Form-Factors